# ImageMagick - Delete Group from Photoshop file

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop

For imagemagick: How do you delete a Photoshop group (and its content layers) by name? Or would another form of layer/group ID be used?

Comment: ImageMagick does not know much if anything about groups and currently cannot delete groups. You can only copy the image and keep specified layers, but not by name. I think you probably need some other tool such as Photoshop or perhaps GIMP

Comment: can it delete a layer by ID?

Comment: or flatten a group to a layer to delete it?

Comment: Imagemagick, as far as I know, does not understand groups in Photoshop, so it cannot delete a layer by ID or flatten a group by group ID. I will defer to anyone who knows otherwise.

Comment: ok thanks...  sorry for the downvote - let me know how i can improve the question.

Comment: I either remove my down-vote or up-voted to cancel someone else's down-vote. I do not know how to improve your question as it is just a how-to. Sorry, but Imagemagick is not the tool to do any of that. It has rather primitive PSD processing capabilities.